# How to update the wrapper after an event

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-hooks, jestjs, enzyme

I am using jest and enzyme to test my React component.
I am facing an issue where I don't get the most recent DOM tree after an event which changes the dom.

Home Component:

```
export class Home extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <RadioFieldClass />
    }
}
```

RadioField Component:

```
const RadioField = props => {
    const [option, setOption] = useState({});
    const handleChange = (e) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setOption({...option, [name]: value});
    }
    return (
        <>
            <p>Select an option</p>
            <div onChange={handleChange}>
                <input type="radio" value="male" name="gender" />Male
                <input type="radio" value="female" name="gender" />Female
                {option.gender && option.gender === 'male' &&
                    <b>You are a male</b>
                }
                {option.gender && option.gender === 'female' &&
                    <i>You are a female</i>
                }
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Test Suit:

```
describe('testing events', () => {
    it('should render b or i tag onChange', () => {
        let wrapper = shallow(<Home />);
        const Radio = wrapper.find('RadioField').dive();
        const event = {target: {value: 'male'}}
        Radio.find('div').props().onChange(event);
        wrapper.update();
        expect(wrapper.find('RadioField').dive().find('div').find('b').exists()).toBe(true);
    })
})
```

The above test suit is failing.

Comment: Show the code of the `Home` component

Comment: updated the question with `Home` component.